# Adding a XSRF-TOKEN via a HTTP Interceptor causes a 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, angular, http-headers

Using a XSRF-TOKEN to prevent against XSRF attacks as I'm passing a JWT threw a cookie for my Angular app. Here is what my `HttpInterceptor` is looking like.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    const respHeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    if (token !== null && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(respHeaderName, token) });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

This causes a 400 Bad Request error to pop up in my console with a message reading: *Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.* If I comment out the line of code where the request is cloned, the error goes away, and my HTTP request goes through perfectly.

My headers in my `.htaccess` look like this.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "Authorization"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT 1:** A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of my PHP code

```
$return = array();

if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    header("HTTP/1.0 200");
    $return["msg"] = "random";
    echo json_encode($return);

} else {

    header("HTTP/1.0 400");
    $return["error_message"] = "HTTP Post variables are not set!";
    $return["friendly_error_message"] = "Client error!";
    echo json_encode($return);

}

exit();
```

And my `verify()` function in my Angular service.

```
verify(email: string, password: string): Observable<JSON> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    let body = new HttpParams();
    body = body.set("email", email);
    body = body.set("password", password);
    return this.http.post<JSON>("http://localhost:80/verify", body, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true, observe: "response" }).pipe(
        map(res => {
            return res.body;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

I've been testing with a "XSRF-TOKEN" session cookie by commenting/un-commenting a line of PHP code. When the session cookie is active, this error happens.

[image: console]

When I delete the cookie, I obviously don't have this problem because the `req.clone()` function never goes through as the conditional isn't met.

Comment: You have not shown your PHP code. Browsers will use OPTION request to your endpoint for "preflight". And it should return an "200 OK" response with proper headers.

Comment: I'll edit my post and throw in my PHP code later today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KoalaYeung check out my edit :)

Comment: Your PHP conditional would only return a "200 OK" when (a) it is a POST request;  and (b) the POST body has the correct email and password. As I said earlier, a preflight request is always an OPTION request. Therefore your logic here would always return "400 Bad Request".

Comment: That makes sense but I guess I just don't understand why this whole "XSRF-TOKEN" thing I'm doing is messing everything up.

Comment: It is not the "XSRF-TOKEN thing" thats messing up. You need to correctly implement the server side code to cater for a XSRF / CSRF workflow.

Comment: Maybe you need to read more on what XSRF / CSRF workflow is doing in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side code is not correctly responding to the preflight request for XSRF / CSRF workflow. You have to return a "200 OK" response to an OPTIONS request so your Angular plugin works:

```php
<?php

$return = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {

    // instead of doing that in .htaccess
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization");

    // a 200 OK response to preflight with empty body
    header("HTTP/1.0 200");

} elseif (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    // presuming all request that are not a preflight
    // must be a POST request.
    header("HTTP/1.0 200");
    $return["msg"] = "random";
    echo json_encode($return);

} else {

    header("HTTP/1.0 400");
    $return["error_message"] = "HTTP Post variables are not set!";
    $return["friendly_error_message"] = "Client error!";
    echo json_encode($return);

}

exit();
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to move all the header statements out of the first `if` block because it was throwing an error, I assume, when the `POST` request hit, because there was no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response. Thanks for the help though!